# a) Prove that if ρ and σ are uniformly equivalent, then they are equivalent;

Tags: real-analysis

Two metrics, $ρ$ and $σ$, on a set $M$ are said to be uniformly equivalent if there exist positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $c_1 ρ(x, y) \le σ(x, y) \le c_2 ρ(x, y)$. for all $x$ and $y$ in $M.$

(a) Prove that if $ρ$ and $σ$ are uniformly equivalent, then they are equivalent.

(b) Let $ M = R^2$. Define $ρ_1 (x, y) ≡ |x_1 − y_1| + |x_2 − y_2|, ρ_2 (x, y) ≡ \sqrt{|x_1 − y_1|^2 +|x_2 − y_2|^2}$ and $ρ_{max}(x, y) ≡ \max\{|x_1 − y_1|, |x_2 − y_2|\}$. Prove that $ρ_1, ρ_2$ and $ρ_{max}$ are uniformly equivalent‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: Does "equivalent" mean that they induce the same topology, or is the term used in a different way here?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that two metrics are equivalent if each of the two topologies they generate is finer than the other. For (a), note that for any open ball $B_\rho(x,r)$ ($r > 0, x \in M$), $B_\sigma(x,rc_1/2) \subset B_\rho(x,r)$ since any $y$ in the former satisfies $\rho(x,y) \leq \sigma(x,y)/c_1 < r/2.$ Thus, $\tau_\rho \subset \tau_\sigma$, where $\tau_{(\cdot)}$ denotes the topology generated by the metric.

A symmetric argument shows the reverse inclusion. For (b), note that 
\begin{align*}
 \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2} &\leq \sqrt{2}\max_i\{|x_i-y_i|\}\\
\max_i\{|x_i-y_i|\} &\leq |x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|\\
|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2| &\leq 2 \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

(a) To show that the two topologies induced by the two metrics coincide, it suffices to show that for all $x \in X$ and $r>0$ there exist $r',r''>0$ such that $B_{\rho}(x,r') \subset B_{\sigma}(x,r)$ and $B_{\sigma}(x,r'')\subset B_{\rho}(x,r)$. Now for example:

$$
\begin{align}
B_{\sigma}(x,c_1 r)&=\{y \in X : \sigma(x,y)<c_1 r\}\\  
                   &\subset\{y\in X : c_1 \rho(x,y)<c_1 r\}\\  
                   &=\{y\in X : \rho(s,y)<r\}\\  
                   &=B_{\rho}(x,r).\\  
\end{align}
$$
The other inclusion is similar.
(b) Try to prove the following inequalities:

$$
\rho_{max}(x,y) \leq \rho_1(x,y) \leq \sqrt{2} \rho_2(x,y) \leq 2 \rho_{max}(x,y)
$$